# Destroying sensitive partition

Tags: physical

I've got multiple partitions on a computer, one for basic, day to day user stuff, and one for pentesting and security. The pentesting partition is encrypted. Could anyone give me, and everyone else, a way to destroy one partition, completely and totally, without wiping the other partition, and making it quick, seamless, and unnoticeable as possible. Think of an enemy operative has a hold of my computer, and I need sensitive information and tools to be erased, but my basic operating system is fine, to prevent suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to have it set up as an encrypted partition.

To wipe, simply lose the passphrase.

That easy.

Sure, you have to use a framework that doesn't leak the passphrase or store it anywhere accessible, but this way has been tried and tested, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way accelerate wiping is to encrypt the partition and then overwrite a necessary disk sector. (As opposed to having to overwrite the whole partition.)

But this is detectable.

One alternative is something called "[Deniable Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption)". TrueCrypt allows you to do this. The idea is to have one encrypted blob of data to decrypt to more than one thing. Depending on the password entered. Example: you encrypt a 100 GB partition. Then you store two sub partitions on it. One grows from the beginning of the partition up. The other sub partition grows from the end of the partition downwards. Then you store say 40 GB of the really secret stuff one sub partition. And 40 GB of mildly offensive porn on the other.